# Run a program by name from PowerShell (similarly to the run box)

Tags: powershell

In Windows we access the **Run box** with `Windows Key + R`. Then we can run a program by name (e.g. firefox, snippingtool). Is there a way to run a program by name from PowerShell?

```
> run firefox
> run snippingtool
```

I have already tried `Start-Process firefox` and it doesn't work.

**Edit**

Oddly enough, from both PowerShell and the Run box, typing just `notepad` opens notepad. However, typing either `firefox` or `snippingtool` works only from the Run box and not from PowerShell.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you question, but you should be able to just type the name of the application into the command line and hit enter.  As long as the application name is on the path, then it should launch.  For example, I can open a powershell terminal and type mspaint.exe and hit enter and Paint launches.

Comment: @David That's what I thought too. It turns out that for some programs, such as `notepad`, I can just type the name of the application into PowerShell and hit enter, whereas for other programs like `firefox` and `snippingtool`, the Run box starts them just from their application name but PowerShell does not.

Comment: You can just type the name of the application (like "notepad" for example) because it is located in the system32 directory within Windows. You can place any program there and call it by name but that is terrible practice. 
Is there a reason that you don't want to use a path to the program you are starting? I normally use a full path with Start-Process when launching programs, personally.

Comment: As @David said: the path to the executable needs to be in your `%PATH%`/`$env:PATH` environment variable. The "Run" dialog behaves differently, because it uses different search paths than CMD and PowerShell.

Comment: @Mokilok Fair enough. The reason I don't want to use a path is because the path is hard to remember and involves more typing.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Is there a way we can have PowerShell use the same path search behavior that the run dialog uses?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin It already does.

Comment: @David Then why does `snippingtool` work from the run dialog and not from PowerShell?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin : See my comment above. Snipping tool is in the System32 directory.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin If you can't be bothered typing it in each time, with powershell open, type "notepad $profile", now create a new variable with the path to your program e.g. $programIwantToRun = "C:\program.exe". Now that variable will be set every time PowerShell opens and all you have to reference is that variable. You should note though that a PowerShell session running under an elevated process (running as administrator) gets a different $Profile to one that is running as a non-elevated process.

Answer (score 3):

The run box uses the `PATH` environment variable but it also uses a set of registry keys.

The key `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` contains subkeys with certain application names, and each of those has a string value called `Path` with the path to the executable. Powershell and the command prompt don't use these.

### Emulating this in Powershell

```powershell
$allCommands = Get-Command -CommandType All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths' | Where-Object { $_.Property -icontains 'Path' } | ForEach-Object {
    $executable = $_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf
    $shortName = $executable -creplace '\.[^.]*$',''
    $path = $_ | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
    $fqPath = $path | Join-Path -ChildPath $executable

    if ( ($allCommands -icontains $executable) -or ($allCommands -icontains $shortName) ) {
        Write-Verbose "Skipping $executable and $shortName because a command already exists with that name."
    } else {
        Write-Verbose "Creating aliases for $executable."
        New-Alias -Name $executable -Value $fqPath
        New-Alias -Name $shortName -Value $fqPath
    }
}
```

This snippet will read the registry and add all of those entries as aliases. It also adds the EXE name without .exe so that you can use the short name.

It checks for existing commands beforehand to make sure that it won't clobber any existing command (of any type).

### Edit

I also created a function you could use to execute an arbitrary application, without modifying the entire environment:

```powershell
function Run-Application {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String[]]
    $Name ,

    [Parameter()]
    [Switch]
    $NoExtension
)

    Begin {
        if (!$NoExtension -and $env:PATHEXT) {
            $exts = $env:PATHEXT -csplit ';'
        } else {
            $exts = @()
        }

        $regStub = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths'
    }

    Process {
        :outer 
        foreach($app in $Name) {
            $cmd2run = $app
            if (Get-Command -Name $cmd2run -ErrorAction Ignore) {
                if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($cmd2run)) {
                    & $cmd2run
                }
                continue :outer
            } elseif ($app -cnotlike '*.*') {
                foreach($ext in $exts) {
                    $cmd2run = "$app$ext"
                    if (Get-Command -Name $cmd2run -ErrorAction Ignore) {
                        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($cmd2run)) {
                            & $cmd2run
                        }
                        continue :outer
                    }
                }
            } 
            $thisReg = $regStub | Join-Path -ChildPath $cmd2run
            $regItem = $thisReg | Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore
            if ($regItem -and $regItem.Property -icontains 'Path') {
                $thisPath = $regItem | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | Join-Path -ChildPath $cmd2run
                if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($thisPath)) {
                    & $thisPath
                }
                continue :outer
            } elseif ($app -cnotlike '*.*') {
                foreach($ext in $exts) {
                    $cmd2run = "$app$ext"
                    $thisReg = $regStub | Join-Path -ChildPath $cmd2run
                    $regItem = $thisReg | Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore
                    if ($regItem -and $regItem.Property -icontains 'Path') {
                        $thisPath = $regItem | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path | Join-Path -ChildPath $cmd2run
                        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($thisPath)) {
                            & $thisPath
                        }
                        continue :outer
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can supply one or more names, with or without extension, via parameter or via pipeline.

If the value has no extension, it uses `PATHEXT` and tries every combination. You can also disable that by using `-NoExtension`.

I used `Run-Application` for verb-noun syntax, but you could always alias it to `run` if you want.

I'm not sure if it will work for you if you had problems with the other code, but it worked very well for me, and I had fun writing it. Hope it's helpful to you or someone else.

### Edit 2

Fixed function so it supports `-WhatIf`.

#### Examples

```powershell
Run-Application notepad

Run-Application firefox,chrome.exe

'notepad.exe','firefox.exe','snippingtool' | Run-Application -Whatif

Run-Application firefox -NoExtension # Should fail
```

Comment: When I run that code, I receive the following error: `Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. At 32 char:23 $fqPath = $path | Join-Path -ChildPath $executable.` In fact, there are six errors when I run that code.

Comment: Any chance you could step through and give me the values of the variables when it throws the error? I'm so far unable to reproduce on my end, but I'm willing to bet I didn't account for some condition or another.

Comment: I had to replace "Ignore" with "SilentlyContinue" for this to work. Ignore is not a valid ErrorAction in PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 3):

As @briantist mentioned in his answer (+1): the "Run" dialog (which [probably calls the `ShellExecuteEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) checks the subkeys of the `App Paths` registry key in addition to the paths in the `$env:PATH` environment variable.

For emulating the behavior of the "Run" dialog I would, however, add the folders to `$env:PATH` instead of creating aliases for each executable:

```
$regkey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths'

$appPaths = Get-ChildItem $regkey |
  Get-ItemProperty |
  ? { $_.'(default)' } |
  select -Expand '(default)' |
  Split-Path -Parent |
  % { [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($_.TrimStart('"')) } |
  select -Unique

$env:PATH += ';' + ($appPaths -join ';')
```

By adding this to a [PowerShell profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx) (e.g. your personal profile `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`), the variable `$env:PATH` of each PowerShell instance you start is updated with the additional paths from the registry. Note, however, that by adding too many folders you might be hitting [length restrictions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/03/9957320.aspx).

Comment: In my test, changing the `PATH` variable at run time did not affect the running environment, and I wasn't able to execute a file in the new directory added to the path.

Comment: @briantist The code only changes the process's copy of the environment variable, which works just fine at runtime. The change is not persistent, though, which is why I suggested to add it to a PowerShell profile.

Comment: The environment variable changed for me (during the session only of course) but trying to run an executable in (now changed) path did not. Did that work for you?

Comment: @briantist Yes, both with using a profile and updating the variable on the fly.

Comment: I just tried it again, and you are correct. I do see the expected behavior. Not sure what I did wrong that first time, though it's the reason I ended up using `New-Alias` instead.

Comment: After adding that script to my profile, emulating *run* now works for more programs than it did previously. While it works for `firefox` and `chrome`, it doesn't work for `opera` nor `snippingtool`. What gives? It seems that some programs *run* from PowerShell without that script, others require that script, and still others need even *more* work.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin As others have already explained to you: some programs can be run right away, because their executables reside in a folder that already is present in `$env:PATH`. The paths of those that are registered in the `App Paths` registry key can be added to `$env:PATH` as described above. If something still doesn't work: check the actual location of that program and the value of `$env:PATH` for the presence of that location. `snippingtool` for instance is located in `%windir%\system32`, which should be in the path by default.