# How can I run vim from PowerShell just by typing vim?

Tags: powershell, vim

I just installed vim. It's awesome. From PowerShell, I want to be able to launch it both via typing `vim` and by typing `vim someFile.txt`.

I can already open vim through the run dialog. Further, it's already in my system PATH. What must I do to launch it from PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If the executable (vim.exe) is in the path, either one of those should work. It works for me.

Comment: I was under the impression that I add the *directory* than contains vim.exe to the Path rather than adding the actual vim.exe to the path.

Comment: That's what it means to say that a file is "in the path"--that it's in one of the directories listed in the path. The path is a list of directories, it cannot contain individual files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's already in the path, it should work.

But you can, alternatively, use an alias via `New-Alias`. If you add that to your profile, it will load every time.

To see how the run box behaves differently from powershell, and how you might get around that, see my answer here:
[Run a program by name from PowerShell (similarly to the run box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414209/run-a-program-by-name-from-powershell-similarly-to-the-run-box/26415077#26415077)

Comment: Hmm. If it should already work, then I wonder why it isn't working. Could it be that I just need to restart PowerShell?

Comment: If you added it to the path outside of powershell (through the system settings dialog), then yes restart powershell because the existing session won't have the updated path. If you added it within powershell (`$env:PATH = whatever`) then it should take effect right away, but will last only for the session.