# Can we trap all commands and modify them before they are passed to powershell?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, automation

I would like to extend powershell so that it supports wider range of commands including support for running a command that matches an executable name in the system. I know many of scripting guys implemented scripts that will help running applications from the system's path or registry. For example, a similar idea here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224166/bash-like-prompt-in-PowerShell-and-app-run I'm asking more that that. I want to type the name of program only and it will invoke the program without extra typing (not even the alias of an extra script)

Roughly, I would like to add support for,

- all run commands. for example,

  PS > notepad++

  PS > chrome

I know 'start chrome' would work. But not all applications would work that way. 
For example, if chrome is the command I would add a 'start ' before it. If the command is matched with other executable. I would send & "\path\to\executable"

Besides, I want to get rid of start from the command. I would also like to add following features,

- some basic mathematical syntaxes supporting log, power, base conversion etc
- some necessary tools (mathematics and other binary necessary
  executable binaries installed by default)

It's 2015. Command prompts and shells are still so dumb. Therefore, I shall write a custom shell. Before reinventing the wheel I would like to ensure that this is already not possible using powershell to extend commands.

I need to access all the commands sent to powershell for execution and modify them before they are executed by powershell.

Comment: What's wrong with just adding entries to $env:PATH or App Paths?

Comment: It's personal feeling. I don't like adding hundred's of locations in the path. I don't think it's an efficient way in Windows. Besides that's not all. Please read the question again.

Comment: Environment variable path has a limit. Consider that too.

People who are downvoting care to leave a comment? Thanks.

Comment: I think that's why Nathan mentioned App Paths, which are a scalable solution.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, joey please give an usage example of app paths.

Comment: The fantastic psreadline module allow you to preprocess each input type in the console :)

Comment: You mean this: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first case, launching certain executables, [see my answer here about why this is happening and how you can deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415077/3905079).

As far as the other stuff, I don't think it's possible to add your own operators, but you can write your own functions of course. You can also use any class/type/library that can be used in .Net, including ones you write yourself.

You can even use `Add-Type` with C# (or VB.net?) code in a string to add functionality. It's quite likely that there's a way to do things you want to in some existing .Net library somewhere, so I would look for those first.

PowerShell is reqlly quite amazing and extensive, as shells go because it has the full power of .Net behind it.

Maybe you could show some [pseudo]code examples of how you want your proposed features to work and then we could post some workarounds.

Comment: The linked article seems to cover App-Path support OK, but I'm not sure what else the OP actually needs.

Comment: @briantist, you didn't get my point. If you look at the codeproject article, you will see I have done something similar before. You are adding Run-Application where I was adding ss. I really want to get rid of that. For other suggestions I agree with you. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, I want to run an app with its name directly, evaluate unsupported math expressions etc. I don't want to start a command with Run-Application or start etc. Understand my point why I am saying they are dumb.

Comment: Look at the first code snippet, not the `Run-Application` function. It does not require you to use anything but the executable name, does not modify the `PATH` environment variable, and can be added to a profile so that its use is transparent.

Comment: Even after that you have to type 'Run-Application app_name'. Right?

Comment: @Atique: No. They're aliases. No extra typing at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, you have to type the alias at least. Right?

Comment: @Atique: You have to type *something*, certainly, but since we do not yet have mind-reading technology, that's unavoidable. You *don't* have to type more than the bare executable name, aliased to its corresponding entry taken from App Paths.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you didn't get what braintist is saying. The alias is for the function/script he has written.

Comment: @Atique: No, it's for that particular executable. The first snippet's code is not hard to read: it loops through and adds aliases corresponding to each command it can find.

Comment: @NathanTuggy sorry I misunderstood. I see now, this can be taken care of using aliases. Of course, we need to load the script every time probably using profile path.

What about the other part: how can we modify commands before it is passed to powershell for execution?